# How can I get the component that raised an event without using a separate variable

Tags: c#, blazor

In Blazor I can get a reference to a component by using the @ref command.

Then I can pass it into an event method as an argument.

```
<button @ref="buttonRef" @onclick="() => OnClick(buttonRef)" />

@code {
    private ElementReference buttonRef;

    private void OnClick(ElementReference button)
    {
    }
}
```

However, this results in a lot of extra boilerplate code when dealing with many fields on a screen.

I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of the backing field `buttonRef` and have the `@onclick` pass in a self-reference from the component that's raising the event.

Something along the lines of:

```
<button @onclick="() => OnClick(@ref)" />
```

which doesn't work.

Comment: What is your goal in passing a reference to the clicked button?  I can think of very few situations where you'd want to do that in Blazor.  Would you mind explaining your purpose a little more?

Comment: Ah, this might be an XY question.  What I'm looking to do is that when a user clicks on a textbox in Blazor, to select the contents.  It automatically happens when tabbing in, but not on click.  And when there's 20 textboxes on a screen, it becomes annoying to track 20 extra variables.

Comment: _"And when there's 20 textboxes on a screen"_   Then it pays of to make a Component. I like @Bennyboy1973's answer but that's still a lot of boilerplate to repeat 20 times.

Comment: The answer to the OP's problem would be one line: `<input onfocus="this.select();"`  The rest is just my way of generating an arbitrary number of bound test inputs.  But I'm curious what you had in mind-- if you have time, can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Short version: in Blazor, you can still use inline javascript just like you would in any HTML page.  I don't think `onclick` will be best because it will make it almost impossible to edit the text.  So I used `onfocus`.  Make sure to drop the `@` symbol.

Long version: the following pattern, where you have a `List` of a class, and then a single instance for storing the selected value, is worth remembering, I think.

```
@foreach (var item in Texts)
{
    <div>
        <input onfocus="this.select();" @bind="item.Text" @onfocusin="()=> SelectedText=item" /> @item.Text
    </div>

}
@if (SelectedText is not null)
{
    <div>
        Text of currently-selected box: @SelectedText.Text
    </div>
}
@code {
    int TextBoxCount = 5;
    class SelectableText { public string Text { get; set; } = ""; } // Can add other properties here.  Allows to bind to text in foreach loop
    List<SelectableText> Texts = new();
    SelectableText SelectedText;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TextBoxCount; i++)
        {
            Texts.Add(new SelectableText());
        }
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```